# clock_t and clock in does not declared in this scope in Qt

Tags: c++

I included time.h in my Qt but its say me `clock_t , clock()  was not declared` in this scope why ?( my qt creator version is **4.2.1**)

(if code needed i can insert it )

[image]

[image: image 2]

Comment: add `#include <time.h>`and
`#include <stdio.h>`, Separate `#include` from `<some.h>`

Comment: do your mean is <time.h> ? i add it and stdio but error is here

Comment: *"if code needed i can insert it "* Yes, it is needed. A screenshot of code is never acceptable.

Comment: thank but its fixed now

Answer (score 3):

Rename your time.h to TimeClass.h or something like that, do not use `time.h`.
Try to add ctime to your time.cpp (or any file that uses clock_t or clock()):

```
#include "TimeClass.h"
#include <ctime>   // add this
```

and then change `clock_t` to `std::clock_t`, `clock()` to `std::clock()`.
In any case, it's better to rename your time.h.

Comment: @masterboy `doesn't work` because your computer is off or there's something more specific?..

Comment: ctime is not known by my Qt its get me a loy of error see image 2 in top

Comment: @masterboy just rename your time.h. This is standard header in c/c++ you shouldn't name your files the same way.

Comment: i reanme it see image 3

Comment: @masterboy read my answer, you also need to add `#include <ctime>` where you use `clock_t` or `clock()`, and you have to change them to `std::clock_t` and `std::clock()` respectively.

Comment: @masterboy do you realize that saying "its get me error" is completely pointless? You need to say what the error is all about

Comment: @masterboy do you have `#include <ctime>` inside your `mytime.h`? You have two options: use ctime with std::clock_t/std::clock() or time.h with clock_t/clock(). Try to change to time.h if ctime doesn't work for you. Also, try to set your compiler to use `-stdc++11`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your own `time.h` header file is masking the `#include <time.h>` which is part of std, so the compiler looks in 'your' `time.h` for the declarations of `clock_t` and `clock()`
.

rename your own header to something else, eg mytime.h and your cpp file to mytime.cpp.

Then in mytime.cpp use

```
#include "mytime.h"
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
```

Comment: @masterboy in mytime.cpp you should include both `mytime.h` and `<time.h>`. In the screenshot 2 I see you only included `mytime.h`

Comment: btw in c++ you should normally use `include <ctime>` , which in turn includes `include <time.h>`, but in this example it does not matter

Comment: OK please say me why its get me this Error ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're having an issue because you're not using the correct namespace. For a lot of classes that ship with c++ (string, vector, etc.) the compiler will complain if you don't declare them as std::string. An easy way to fix that is to put `using namespace std;` at the top of your .cpp file.

Comment: please see images

Answer (score -1):

its fixed without ctime i **writed it again** and result was changed , finally i see it get me wrong result and when i update code its get me wrong results too such as clock_t no such file , but when i write it again its accepted thanks for any one who helped me to understand this feature of Qt